# How can I retrieve the matching records from mentioned file format in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

```
XYZNA0000778800Z
16123000012300321000000008000000000000000
16124000012300322000000007000000000000000
17234000012300323000000005000000000000000
17345000012300324000000004000000000000000
17456000012300325000000003000000000000000
9
XYZNA0000778900Z
16123000012300321000000008000000000000000
16124000012300322000000007000000000000000
17234000012300323000000005000000000000000
17345000012300324000000004000000000000000
17456000012300325000000003000000000000000
9
```

I have above file format from which I want to find a matching record. For example, match a number(7789) on line starting with XYZ and once matched look for a matching number (7345) in lines below starting with 1 until it reaches to line starting with 9. retrieve the entire line record. How can I accomplish this using shell script, awk, sed or any combination.

Expected Output:

```
 XYZNA0000778900Z
 17345000012300324000000004000000000000000
```

Comment: Please add the output you want. Do you want all lines up to the `9`, or only the lines until (including?)  7345. Or  only the line with 7345 ?

Answer (score 1):

With sed one can do:

```
$ sed -n '/^XYZ.*7789/,/^9$/{/^1.*7345/p}' file
17345000012300324000000004000000000000000
```

Breakdown:

```
sed -n '                                ' # -n disabled automatic printing
        /^XYZ.*7789/,                     # Match line starting with XYZ, and
                                          # containing 7789
                            /^1.*7345/p   # Print line starting with 1 and
                                          # containing 7345, which is coming
                                          # after the previous match
                     /^9$/ {           }  # Match line that is 9
```

`range { stuff }` will execute `stuff` when it's inside `range`, in this case the range is starting at `/^XYZ.*7789/` and ending with `/^9$/`.

`.*` will match anything but newlines zero or more times.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use awk:

```
awk -v rid=7789 -v fid=7345 -v RS='\n9\n' -F '\n' 'index($1, rid) { for(i = 2; i < $NF; ++i) { if(index($i, fid)) { print $i; next } } }' filename
```

This works as follows:

- `-v RS='\n9\n'` is the meat of the whole thing. Awk separates its input into records (by default lines). This sets the record separator to `\n9\n`, which means that records are separated by lines with a single `9` on them. These records are further separated into fields, and
- `-F '\n'` tells awk that fields in a record are separated by newlines, so that each line in a record becomes a field.
- `-v rid=7789 -v fid=7345` sets two awk variables `rid` and `fid` (meant by me as record identifier and field identifier, respectively. The names are arbitrary.) to your search strings. You could encode these in the awk script directly, but this way makes it easier and safer to replace the values with those of a shell variables (which I expect you'll want to do).

Then the code:

```
index($1, rid) {               # In records whose first field contains rid  
  for(i = 2; i < $NF; ++i) {   # Walk through the fields from the second
    if(index($i, fid)) {       # When you find one that contains fid
      print $i                 # Print it,
      next                     # and continue with the next record.
    }                          # Remove the "next" line if you want all matching
  }                            # fields.
}
```

Note that multi-character record separators are not strictly required by POSIX awk, and I'm not certain if BSD awk accepts it. Both GNU awk and mawk do, though.

**EDIT:** Misread question the first time around.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the whole block matching the conditions, one can use:

```
$ sed -n '/^XYZ.*7789/{:s;N;/\n9$/!bs;/\n1.*7345/p}' file
XYZNA0000778900Z
16123000012300321000000008000000000000000
16124000012300322000000007000000000000000
17234000012300323000000005000000000000000
17345000012300324000000004000000000000000
17456000012300325000000003000000000000000
9
```

This works by reading lines between `^XYZ.*7779` and `^9$` into the pattern
space. And then printing the whole thing if `^1.*7345` can be matches:

```
sed -n '                                         ' # -n disables printing
        /^XYZ.*7789/{                           }  # Match line starting
                                                   # with XYZ that also contains 7789
                     :s;                           # Define label s
                        N;                         # Append next line to pattern space
                          /\n9$/!bs;               # Goto s unless \n9$ matches
                                    /\n1.*7345/p   # Print whole pattern space
                                                   # if \n1.*7345 matches
```

Answer (score 0):

an extendable `awk` script can be

```
$ awk '/^9$/{s=0} s&&/7345/; /^XYZ/&&/7789/{s=1} ' file
```

set flag s when line starts with XYZ and contains 7789; reset when line is just 9, and print when flag is set and contains pattern 7345.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^XYZ/h;//!H;/^9/!b;x;/^XYZ[^\n]*7789/!b;/7345/p' file
```

Use the option `-n` for the grep-like nature of sed. Gather up records beginning with `XYZ` and ending in `9`. Reject any records which do not have `7789` in the header. Print any remaining records that contain `7345`.

If the `7345` will always follow the header,this could be shortened to:

```
sed -n '/^XYZ/h;//!H;/^9/!b;x;/^XYZ[^\n]*7789.*7345/p' file
```

If all records are well-formed (begin `XYZ` and end in `9`) then use:

```
sed -n '/^XYZ/h;//!H;/^9/!b;x;/^[^\n]*7789.*7345/p' file
```